# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_date_time-vc141-mt-1_65_1.lib'

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile boost in visual studio 2017.

boost version is 1.65.1

I have included the boost libraries include path in the additional Include directories and
lib path in Additional lib dir.

In the preprocessor I have added the following tags - BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB;BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK;
any assistance will be helpful in resolving the issue.

Comment: Does `boost_date_time-vc141-mt-1_65_1.lib` exist in the directory you added to "Additional Library Directories"?

Comment: If it does exist make sure that you are not mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just to correct my question : the error that i am getting is :

**LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-1_55.lib'**

I have installed the 64 bit version.

I am trying to compile boost in visual studio 2017.

boost version is 1.65.1

I have included the boost libraries include path in the additional Include directories and lib path in Additional lib dir.

In the preprocessor I have added the following tags:

BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB;
BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK;

any assistance will be helpful in resolving the issue.

Comment: You may want to EDIT your question instead of posting an answer saying it is an Edit..

Comment: When you need to add more detail into your question. Please edit instead of posting an answer